# How can I emit events from an Express controller, using Socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a working setup in my main `index.js` file, so far working ok:

```js
const http = require('http')
const httpServer = http.createServer(app)

const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST']
  }
})
io.on('connection', socket => {
  // When a user connects to the socket logs it to the shell.
  console.log(`user connected (${socket.id})`)
  // console.log(socket) // testing

  // Send a 'connected' event when the connection is available.
  io.emit('connected', socket.id)

[...more code...]
exports.io = io
```

At the bottom I'm trying to export the `io` instance, but I don't know how to use it from a controller. So far I'm printing it out to check its contents (an object with several properties):

```js
{
io: <ref *1> Server {
_events: [Object: null prototype] {},
_eventsCount: 0,
_maxListeners: undefined,
_nsps: Map(1) { '/' => [Namespace] },
...
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to emit events to some rooms using this object. When i try to do something like `io.to(req.uid).emit('notify', 'testing')`  from any controller (other than my main `index.js`), I get the `TypeError: io.to is not a function`.
So the question is, how to make the connection available to use anywhere else in my app?

Comment: When you're using the legacy commonjs format in Node, the exports object is a property on `module`, so the syntax is `module.exports = ...`, not `exports = ....`.

Comment: if you're getting `io.to` is not a function, then you're not importing and exporting it properly.  We would need to see exactly how you're doing that in both files.   `exports.io = io` is fine for the export if the import matches that appropriately.  Show us the importing code.

Comment: I'm importing like this: `const io = require('../../index')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, the answer was looking at us from the beginning. When I was printing the object, at the very top there was the `io` property (always a good idea to print stuff), which was nested inside the `io` import.

So to invoke the `emit` method, I had to call it as: `io.io.to(userId).emit('notify', data)`